# CPU usage less than a threshold and more than one node present - Prometheus

Tags: prometheus

I am trying to create a alert rule in prometheus so that it fires an alert when the avg CPU usage of all nodes with label agentpool="worker" for last 3 mins has been below 30%.

Right now, I am able to get alert for ANY node with CPU usage less than 30% for last 3 mins using

```
- alert: NodeCPUUtilizationLow
    expr: instance:node_cpu:rate:sum * 100 < 30
    labels:
        severity: none
    annotations:
        description: CPU utilization has been lower than 30% for last 3 minutes (current value is {{$value}})
```

What should be the expr so that it alerts only for nodes having agentpool="worker" label? I am able to list the nodes with label agentpool="worker" using `kube_node_labels{label_agentpool="worker"}`.

How can I do the same for pods? I want a similar alert: if avg CPU usage is below a threshold for all the pods/containers having label `app=web`

I am running prometheus on kubernetes. It was installed using helm charts from here: https://github.com/coreos/prometheus-operator/tree/master/helm/

Output:

**instance:node_cpu:rate:sum * 100 < 30**

```
{instance="10.240.0.187:9100"}  26.466666666668715
```

**kube_node_labels{label_agentpool="worker"}**

```
kube_node_labels{endpoint="kube-state-metrics",instance="10.240.0.187:8080",job="kube-prometheus-exporter-kube-state",label_agentpool="worker",label_beta_kubernetes_io_arch="amd64",label_beta_kubernetes_io_instance_type="Standard_B2s",label_beta_kubernetes_io_os="linux",label_failure_domain_beta_kubernetes_io_region="southcentralus",label_failure_domain_beta_kubernetes_io_zone="0",label_kubernetes_azure_com_cluster="dev-kube-cluster",label_kubernetes_io_hostname="k8s-worker-22588695-1",label_kubernetes_io_role="agent",namespace="monitoring",node="k8s-worker-22588695-1",pod="kube-prometheus-exporter-kube-state-854f846569-8lnk2",service="kube-prometheus-exporter-kube-state"}   1
kube_node_labels{endpoint="kube-state-metrics",instance="10.240.0.187:8080",job="kube-prometheus-exporter-kube-state",label_agentpool="worker",label_beta_kubernetes_io_arch="amd64",label_beta_kubernetes_io_instance_type="Standard_B2s",label_beta_kubernetes_io_os="linux",label_failure_domain_beta_kubernetes_io_region="southcentralus",label_failure_domain_beta_kubernetes_io_zone="1",label_kubernetes_azure_com_cluster="dev-kube-cluster",label_kubernetes_io_hostname="k8s-worker-22588695-0",label_kubernetes_io_role="agent",namespace="monitoring",node="k8s-worker-22588695-0",pod="kube-prometheus-exporter-kube-state-854f846569-8lnk2",service="kube-prometheus-exporter-kube-state"}   1
```

Answer (score 0):

`instance:node_cpu:rate:sum` is probably a https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/recording_rules/

So you can either add a new recording rule to Prometheus to sum the CPU of worker nodes or use the corresponding query directly.